# Facebook: how to retrieve all the activity on a domain (www.example.com) by user's friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making an app in which I will analyze user's friends activity on different domains.

I will get the user authorized on my website/app. After that is it possible to get recent activity on a website by friend-circle? If yes how?